# How to replace the missing values in Age column from Titanic/kaggle project

Tags: r, feature-engineering

The code below doesn't give any errors but it doesn't iterate after the first observation, so it's useless. I tried using sapply without any improvement and I don't know if it's a smart approach to use it in conjunctions with the other functions...
Any idea how to improve my code is much appreciated.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(train)) {
  if (is.na(train[i,5])) {
    if (grepl("Master", train$Name, fixed=TRUE) == TRUE) {
          train$Age[i] = round(mean(train$Age[train$Name == "Master"], na.rm = TRUE), digits = 2)
        } else if (grepl("Miss",train$Name, fixed=TRUE) == TRUE) {
      train$Age[i] = round(mean(train$Age[train$Name == "Miss"], na.rm = TRUE), digits = 2)
        } else if (grepl("Mrs",train$Name, fixed=TRUE) == TRUE) {
      train$Age[i] = round(mean(train$Age[train$Name == "Mrs"], na.rm = TRUE), digits = 2)
        } else if (grepl("Mr",train$Name, fixed=TRUE) == TRUE) {
      train$Age[i] = round(mean(train$Age[train$Name == "Mr"], na.rm = TRUE), digits = 2)
        } else if (grepl("Dr",train$Name, fixed=TRUE) == TRUE) {
      train$Age[i] = round(mean(train$Age[train$Name == "Dr"], na.rm = TRUE), digits = 2)
    } 
  }
}
```